# General solution of higher order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this equation:
$$y''' -y'' +y' -y =0.$$

I got the characteristic equation:
$$r^3 -r^2 +r -1 =0$$
and factored by grouping to get:
$$(r+1)(r+1)(r-1) =0$$

so that the roots are $r=1$ and $r=-1$ (repeated).

The problem I have now is getting the general solution - since one of the roots is repeated, would the general solution be
$$y(x) =c_1e^{-x} +c_2e^{-x} +c_3e^x,$$
$$y(x) =c_1e^{-x} +c_2xe^{-x} +c_3e^x,$$
or 
$$y(x) =c_1e^{-x} +c_2xe^{-x} +c_3x^2e^x,$$

or something different? I'm completely lost so any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $(a+bx)e^{-x}+ce^x$

Comment: Are you sure about the factorization? I see $(r-1)(r^2+1)=0$, without repeated roots.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).